# Paste date in new column if condition is true in another R

Tags: r

I want to extract the date from a variable if the condition in another variable is true.

Example: if comorbidity1==10, extract the date from smr_01, otherwise NA

I also need to do this for if if comorbidity1==11 OR comorbidity1==12, extract the date from smr_01, otherwise NA

This is what I want my data to look like

```
comorbidity1  smr_01    NewDate
1             20120607  NA
10            20120607  20120607
10            20120613  20120613
3             20121103  NA
6             20150607  NA
12            20140509  NA
11            20120405  NA
```

I have tried this

```
fulldata$NewDate<-ifelse(fulldata$comorbidity1==10, fulldata$smr_01, NA)
```

but it is not pasting the date in the correct format.

what I am getting looks like this

```
comorbidity1  smr_01    NewDate
1             20120607  NA
10            20120607  4675
10            20120613  17856
3             20121103  NA
6             20150607  NA
12            20140509  NA
11            20120405  NA
```

smr_01 is classed as a date

Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but it is not pasting the date in the correct format."?

Comment: The syntax of your code looks correct, can you show the output that you are getting and how it differs from the expected output?

Comment: so normally the dates look like above but it seems to be pasting them as numbers that I cannot make sense of e.g. 17654. Edited the question above

Comment: The newDate might be initialized as a numeric and not as a date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try :

```
df$NewDate <- as.Date(NA)
inds <- df$comorbidity1 == 10
#For more than 1 value use %in%
#inds <- df$comorbidity1 %in% 10:12
df$NewDate[inds] <- df$smr_01[inds]
df
```

Comment: When I run line three I get the error

Error in NextMethod(.Generic):
NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Comment: Use `%in%`, `inds <- df$comorbidity1 %in% 10`

Comment: Sorted! 

If the %in% 14 OR 26 would I separate with a , or a | ?

Comment: Use it as a vector : `inds <- df$comorbidity1 %in% c(14, 26)`